# How to aggregate data by date in R

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a problem in R. I want to aggregate data in R that has a `date` variable, a `character` variable and a `numeric` variable. The structure of my database is like this:

```
Date          ID         Mount
01/05/2013    1100        100
01/05/2013    1100        500
01/05/2013    11300       200
01/05/2013    11300       500
19/09/2013    4500        1000
19/09/2013    4500        3000
19/09/2013    5679        200
19/09/2013    5679        300
20/09/2013    4519        1000
20/09/2013    4519        2000
20/09/2013    5001        200
20/09/2013    5001        200
```

I want to aggregate my database first by date and second by ID, something like this:

```
Date         ID     Mount
01/05/2013   1100    600
             11300   700
19/09/2013   4500    4000
             5679    500 
20/09/2013   4519    3000
             5001    400
```

I was trying with `aggregate()` function but it only gives me `date` and `mount` and I can't put `ID` variable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you use a `+` in `aggregate()`? Like `aggregate(Mount ~ ID + Date)`

Comment: @Hugh I tried with that but it give each date with the same ID and not an aggregate value with each ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dt)
dt[,list(sum(Mount)), by = c("Date","ID")]
```

Comment: @Duck, did you expect to get something different?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for

```
> result <-aggregate(Mount~Date + ID, sum, data=df )
> (result <- result[order(result$Date), ])
        Date    ID Mount
1 01/05/2013  1100   600
6 01/05/2013 11300   700
2 19/09/2013  4500  4000
5 19/09/2013  5679   500
3 20/09/2013  4519  3000
4 20/09/2013  5001   400
```

`df` is your data.frame

Comment: That is fine but how can I group by `date` for example first should appear the group of `01/05/2013` after group of `19/09/2013` and finally group of `20/09/2013` @Jilber